# Strange 'new' constructor

Tags: c++, qt

I met the following code while inspecting Qt sources:

```
template <typename T>
Q_INLINE_TEMPLATE void QList<T>::node_construct(Node *n, const T &t)
{
    if (QTypeInfo<T>::isLarge || QTypeInfo<T>::isStatic) n->v = new T(t);
    else if (QTypeInfo<T>::isComplex) new (n) T(t);
#if (defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__INTEL_COMPILER) || defined(__IBMCPP__)) && !defined(__OPTIMIZE__)
    // This violates pointer aliasing rules, but it is known to be safe (and silent)
    // in unoptimized GCC builds (-fno-strict-aliasing). The other compilers which
    // set the same define are assumed to be safe.
    else *reinterpret_cast<T*>(n) = t;
#else
    // This is always safe, but penaltizes unoptimized builds a lot.
    else ::memcpy(n, static_cast<const void *>(&t), sizeof(T));
#endif
}
```

It has a strange `new` instruction:

```
new (n) T(t);
```

As far as I understood, it seems not to be a typecast. What does this construction mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is `placement new`. It is just calling a constructor with an address. So, an object of type `T` will be constructed at the location `n`. It also looks to be a placement new invoking a copy constructor.